# Where is the bug in this merge sort implementation of split inversions

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

I am trying to count the `number of inversions` in an array using `merge sort`.

The idea being that the merge step naturally lends itself to what an inversion is: the `ith` element being greater than the `jth` element.

```
def merge_and_count(x, y, result, count):
    i, j = 0, 0

    while i < len(x) and j < len(y):
        if x[i] > y[j]:
            result.append(y[j])
            j += 1
            count += 1
        else:
            result.append(x[i])
            i += 1

    result += x[i:]
    result += y[j:]

    return result, count

def sort_and_count(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        return array, 0

    count = 0
    result = []

    mid = len(array)//2

    x = array[:mid]
    y = array[mid:]

    x, c1 = sort_and_count(x)
    y, c2 = sort_and_count(y)

    result, c3 = merge_and_count(x, y, result, count)

    return result, (c1+c2+c3)

def main():
    array = [1,3,5,2,4,6]
    result, count = sort_and_count(array)
    print("there are", count, "split inversion")
    print(result)
```

However this is printing `2` when I the answer should be `3`

Comment: For which list do you get the unexpected result?

Comment: @trincot the list in the main method `[1,3,5,2,4,6]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug in your `merge_and_count` function. It should be:

```
if x[i] > y[j]:
     result.append(y[j])
     j += 1
     count += len(x) - i # It's not +1 here
```

When you append the next element from `y` to the result, it forms an inversion with all elements from `x` that haven't been added yet. There're exactly `len(x) - i` such elements.